# Attributes MS_ appears in the property name in ApplicationInsights

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-application-insights, serilog

After logging information in ApplicationInsights using a Serilog, the following attributes MS_ appears in the property name. What does it mean and can it be removed?

MS_OperationContext
MS_HostInstanceId
MS_FunctionName

Comment: I found that MS_TriggerDetails is always `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]`, or maybe sometimes a different type of dictionary, but always just the type. https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/55f3d9a7c8e0f38c9ad31b94585c9d395eeb7f57/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host/Loggers/Logger/LoggerExtensions.cs#L245 https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/55f3d9a7c8e0f38c9ad31b94585c9d395eeb7f57/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host/Executors/IFunctionInstance.cs#L14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After logging information in ApplicationInsights using a Serilog, the following attributes MS_ appears in the property name. What does it mean and can it be removed?

It seems its property naming or custom dimension naming convention is by design that way, i.e. `MS_PropertyName`

```
namespace Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A collection of constants used for logging scope keys.
    /// </summary>
    public static class ScopeKeys
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// A key identifying the function invocation id.
        /// </summary>
        public const string FunctionInvocationId = "MS_FunctionInvocationId";

        /// <summary>
        /// A key identifying the function name.
        /// </summary>
        public const string FunctionName = "MS_FunctionName";

        /// <summary>
        /// A key identifying the event starting with the current scope
        /// </summary>
        public const string Event = "MS_Event";

        /// <summary>
        /// A key identifying the current host instance.
        /// </summary>
        public const string HostInstanceId = "MS_HostInstanceId";

        /// <summary>
        /// A key identifying the current invocation trigger details.
        /// </summary>
        public const string TriggerDetails = "MS_TriggerDetails";
    }
}
```

You can refer to [Custom dimension in app insight changed name for FunctionName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/268195/custom-dimension-in-app-insight-changed-name-for-f.html), [ScopeKeys.cs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/3f4ec78be9f43bb041937425ced00b341883aa42/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host/Loggers/Logger/Constants/ScopeKeys.cs)  and 
[LogWarning shows LogLevel as Information](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/1307)

Comment: But why is this naming used specifically when logging is with Serilog?  When logging via TelemetryClient directly, these properties are named without MS_.

Comment: You can refer to [serilog](https://github.com/serilog/serilog) and [Default Name](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/pull/1148)